# Does openAI/chatGPT has an API's to Answer Questions from Multiple File uploads? and Does openAI/chatGPT file upload API support docx/pdf files?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

**Does openAI/chatGPT support docx/pdf file upload too?**

I want to upload multiple files to openAI/chatGPT. I tried it with https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/create and I was successfully able to upload in Json lines format, can it support docx/pdf?

**Which openAI/chatGPT API can be used to ask questions on multiple files uploaded to openAI/chatGPT?**

The files are long and many so I cannot read them and ask questions as suggested in this article
https://plainenglish.io/blog/using-gpt-to-answer-questions-from-multiple-text-files

Please share some useful API to solve my problem

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you explore the library langchain you will discover that it allows reading multiple pdf files, there is an import "from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader" which helps doing it.
It then offers the QA functionality that you require.

below is a quick start to start doing it:

```
import os
import sys

from credentials import OPENAI_API_KEY

query = sys.argv[1]

from langchain.indexes.vectorstore import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=OPENAI_API_KEY


loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("pdfs")
print("loader", loader)
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

print(index.query(query))
```

you can run ask questioning it by running:

`python model.py "provide the name of certifiations in the resume"`